# Paginación en Wordpres para una página de resultados

Tags: wordpress, paginación

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en WordPress y necesito crear una paginación en la página de resultados del Blog.

Es un custom template:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Search.php
 */

get_header(); ?>
```

Llamo la cantidad de resultados con este código:

```
$wp_query->found_posts;
```

Pero no sé cómo hacer un loop personalizado con los resultados para traer la cantidad necesaria por página y pues poder pasarle los datos a la función de paginación. `paginate_links();`

Quedo muy agradecido.

Comment: fijate como lo arma [twentyseventeen](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/search.php) if have posts, while thepost, si es un query personalizado habra que hacer un reset query al final ( pero si es el template de search results funciona igual q el main loop )

Comment: La necesito numérica, y algo que no sé como configurar es la cantidad de posts por página. sin un loop personalizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con algo como esto, agrega el código al finalizar el while, basicamente obtenemos todas las paginas con **paginate_links();** y las recorremos para crear la paginación.

```
<?php

    // Recorriendo objetos
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    /* Pagination */
    global $wp_query;
    // Verificar el numero de paginas
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) return; 
    $big = 999999999; // Necesita un número entero improbable
    // Crear la paginación
    $pages = paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                'type'  => 'array',
         ) );
        // Mostrar la paginacion en pantalla
         if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
            // $paged obtiene las paginas
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
            echo '<div class="paginationSection">';
            echo '<ul class="pagination">';
            // Recorrer todas las paginas
            foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                echo "<li>$page</li>";
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```